# Does signing make any sense when encrypting with secret key is used?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature

When I use secret key which only one server know for symmetric encryption done with `XChaCha20-Poly1305`, is any benefit to use signing aswell? As long as only one server knows the secret, doesn't it also work as a signature? Are there any disadvantages of this solution? I also think that `XChaCha20-Poly1305` would be more secure than signatures as it provides 256 bits of security, unlike Ed25519 (128 bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A signature is to provide proof to a third party, that a message was created (or at least signed) by a specific sender. Since both client and server share the same secret it is impossible to proof to a third party which of client or server has created the message.

If instead all what you need is integrity protection (i.e. detecting tampering of the encrypted data) for the communication between client and server, then ChaCha20-Poly1305 and its variants are sufficient since they provide authenticated encryption and have thus builtin integrity protection.